# NodeJs - Bluebird promise.resolve(value) is undefined

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a service method that creates an object with mongoose which I am attempting to rewrite from callbacks to promises:

```
var Booking = require("../models/booking");
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var notificationEmitter = require('../events/notificationEmitter').NotificationEmitter;

exports.createBooking = function(/* many arguments */){

var booking = new Booking();

... omitted details of adding to booking object...

booking.save().then(function(booking){
    notificationEmitter.emit('createdBooking', booking);
    return Promise.resolve(booking);
}).catch(function(err){
    return Promise.reject(err);
});
};
```

And in my unit test:

```
 bookingService.createBooking(/* all the required values */)
     .then(function(booking){
         assert.notEqual(booking, null);
         done();
     }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        assert.fail();
        done();
     });
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
```

From my unit test. I've debugged and the last line hit is

```
return Promise.resolve(booking);
```

Why am I not getting a promise returned?

Comment: Turn on warnings! Bluebird will find these errors for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not returning any value from `createBooking`. Change to:

```
exports.createBooking = function(/* many arguments */){

var booking = new Booking();

// other code, and:

return booking.save().then(function(booking){
//^^^^ return here


    notificationEmitter.emit('createdBooking', booking);
    return Promise.resolve(booking);
}).catch(function(err){
    return Promise.reject(err);
});
};
```